# Should I notarise my transcript or attest it?

Tags: united-states, transcript-of-records

US universities ask for an official transcript. Can I send a notarised copy of my transcript? If yes, is it better to attest it by my university officials or notarise it?

Answer (score 10):

When a US university asks for official transcripts, they are asking for transcripts to be sent directly from the institution at which the coursework was completed or the degree earned.

If your previous institution cannot send transcripts directly, find out from the US university what their specific requirements are. For example, see [this FAQ from the University of Mississippi](http://international.olemiss.edu/official-officially-certified-notarized/), which also describes how to get *officially certified* transcripts in case your institution cannot directly issue official transcripts.

Comment: Overseas universities may not have a mechanism for issuing transcripts directly to US universities.

Comment: @aeismail good point, see update.